# Plot HIST of a pandas DataframeGroupbySeries

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

I'm working with a small dataframe with this [codecademy: data](https://content.codecademy.com/PRO/paths/data-science/python-portfolio-project-starter-files.zip)

I'm trying to print data to make a small analysis with the following code:

```py
data = pd.read_csv('insurance.csv')

   age     sex     bmi  children smoker     region      charges
0   19  female  27.900         0    yes  southwest  16884.92400
1   18    male  33.770         1     no  southeast   1725.55230
2   28    male  33.000         3     no  southeast   4449.46200
3   33    male  22.705         0     no  northwest  21984.47061
4   32    male  28.880         0     no  northwest   3866.85520

data.groupby('sex').region.hist()
```

[image]

The code returns a pandas series where the first element is subplot1 and the second subplot2.

The code plots them on the same figure, and I'm unable to plot them separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To produce a histogram for each column based on gender:

  - `'children'` and `'smoker'` look different because the number is discrete with only 6 and 2 unique values, respectively.
  - `data.groupby('sex').hist(layout=(1, 4), figsize=(12, 4), ec='k', grid=False)` alone will produce the graph, but without an easy way to add a title.
- Producing the correct visualization often involves reshaping the data for the plotting API.
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.2`, `matplotlib 3.4.2`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import pandas as pd

# load data
data = pd.read_csv('insurance.csv')

# convert smoker from a string to int value; hist doesn't work on object type columns
data.smoker = data.smoker.map({'no': 0, 'yes': 1})

# group each column by sex; data.groupby(['sex', 'region']) is also an option
for gender, df in data.groupby('sex'):

    # plot a hist for each column
    axes = df.hist(layout=(1, 5), figsize=(15, 4), ec='k', grid=False)

    # extract the figure object from the array of axes
    fig = axes[0][0].get_figure()

    # add the gender as the title
    fig.suptitle(gender)
```

[image]

[image]

- In regards to `data.groupby('sex').region.hist()` in the OP, this is a count plot, which shows counts of gender for each region; it is not a histogram.
- [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) by default computes a frequency table of the factors

```py
ax = pd.crosstab(data.region, data.sex).plot(kind='bar', rot=0)
ax.legend(title='gender', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

### Use [`seaborn.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html)

- This requires converting the data from a wide to long format, which is done with [`pandas.DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.read_csv('insurance.csv')
data.smoker = data.smoker.map({'no': 0, 'yes': 1})

# convert the dataframe from a wide to long form
df = data.melt(id_vars=['sex', 'region'])

# plot
p = sns.displot(data=df, kind='hist', x='value', col='variable', row='region', hue='sex',
                multiple='dodge', common_bins=False, facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': False})
```

[image]